# log4j2 and logback dont work together

Tags: logback, log4j2, slf4j-api

I want use struts 2.5 over logback but everything log to file only write to console of tomcat

i used jar as below:

- struts 2.5.13
- logback-core 1.2.3
- logback-classic 1.2.3
- log4j-api 2.9.1
- log4j-to-slf4j 2.9.1
- slf4j-api 1.7.25

Many thanks

Comment: The logging libraries seem ok. Can you show your logback configuration? Also it’s unclear what you want to achieve and what is actually happening. Please add more detail for both of these.

Comment: @RemkoPopma i  deploy on tomcat 7 java 8 on window  and but nothing save to file   logback.xml  <configuration>
 <appender name="STDOUT"
  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">  
  <file>/app/a.log</file>
  <encoder>
   <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread]
    [%logger:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
 </appender>
 <root level="debug">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </root>
</configuration>

Comment: Please add the configuration to the question. It’s too hard to read in a comment.